# Php 5.6 (fpm) - old files with mysql commands works - How when it is depreacated?

Tags: php, mysql

I installed php 5.6 fpm, and running it with nginx in front.

I began to changes some of my files containing old mysql commands because manual says that was depreceated, but all code just works?

phpinfo shows - PHP Version 5.6.5

and aditional ini files are:

/opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-bz2.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-dom.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-exif.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-gettext.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-pgsql.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-phar.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-posix.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-shmop.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-simplexml.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-sysvsem.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-sysvshm.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-xml.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-xmlwriter.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/20-xsl.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/30-mysql.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_pgsql.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/30-wddx.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/30-xmlreader.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/40-igbinary.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/40-json.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/40-zip.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/50-mongo.ini, /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.d/50-redis.ini

what is happening here?

Answer (score 2):

They are deprecated.  But not removed.  You should get a E_DEPRECATED error if you turn all errors on.

http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: but i am not getting E_DEPRECATED

Comment: What is your error level set to?
add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of one of your files that uses mysql_ functions and then execute that code.